# Approximating the median of a $\Gamma(\alpha,1)$ distribution with $0<\alpha<1$

Tags: gamma-distribution, median

Is there a good approximation (or useful bounds) for the median $\nu_\alpha$ of a $\Gamma(\alpha,1)$ distribution with $0<\alpha<1$?

I have only been able to find things like [Berg & Pedersen (2006, *Methods and Applications of Analysis*)](https://doi.org/10.4310/MAA.2006.v13.n1.a4), who generalize earlier work of [Choi (1994, *Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society*)](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-1994-1195477-8) and give a good asymptotic expression for $\nu_\alpha$ as $\alpha\to\infty$, which works pretty well for $\alpha\geq 1$ - but nothing whatsoever for $0<\alpha<1$.

(I am interested in this because would like to update [my earlier Q&A](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/389318/1352) about minimizing MAPEs and other forecasting errors for gamma distributed future outcomes. So far, it only works if $\alpha\geq 2$, and the case $1<\alpha<2$, which leads to getting $\nu_\alpha$ for $0<\alpha<1$ as above, is missing.)

Comment: Since most stats packages implement an inverse-cdf (quantile function) for the gamma, even when $\alpha<1$, presumably that could be used. Or were you after a closed-form expression?

Comment: @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica: yes, and that works well numerically, and yes, I was hoping for a closed form similar to the one in section 6 in Berg & Pedersen (2006).

Comment: This is probably extremely naive, but couldn'' you calculate the medians numerically with `qgamma` for $\alpha$ between $0$ and $1$ and then fit some sort of polynomial model or something else to these?

Comment: @COOLSerdash: that would be a possibility, yes. The convexity of the median as a function of $\alpha$ ([Berg & Pedersen, 2008](https://doi.org/10.1007/s11512-006-0037-2)) would likely help. What I am looking for is error guarantees, so perhaps someone has already done something along these lines using interpolation.

Comment: @S.Kolassa-ReinstateMonica The newest reference I could find is by [You (2017)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X17300173). But this approximation is again not suitable for small $\alpha$s, as far as I can see.

Comment: @COOLSerdash: thanks for the reference, I wasn't aware of that. Unfortunately, it again doesn't help, it's only for $\alpha=n+1$ with natural $n$, as for most other papers on this question. I assume it may work for real $n$, but I'm interested in smaller shape parameters.

Comment: How accurate do you need the approximation to be and how complicated are you willing it to be?  For instance, the crude approximation $(\Gamma(1+\alpha)/2)^{1/\alpha}$ works well for $\alpha \lt 0.2$ and decently for $\alpha\lt 0.4,$ but requires an evaluation of $\Gamma.$

Comment: @whuber: anything with approximation bounds would be useful. Do you have something along these lines?

Comment: I have one crude theoretical result and can obtain numerical results with guaranteed bounds based on regressing the median (for a range of $\alpha$ in an interval $(\epsilon,1)$) against monomials in $\alpha,$ $\log(\alpha),$ and $1/\alpha.$ Those quickly produce approximation errors of less than $10^{-6}$--but they're not insightful, not much use for analysis, and are probably more computationally expensive than finding the median. Two simple approximations exist for $\alpha\le 0.2$ and $0.2\le \alpha \le 1;$ they get you two significant figures.

Comment: @whuber: That sounds interesting. Do you have pointers to any of those results? Do the simple approximations come with bounds? The Berg & Pedersen expansion seems to work well even non-asymptotically, it's the missing bounds that bothers me.

Comment: I see you beat me to that good lower bound. I came up with the same a few weeks later, in the discussion on Wikipedia, at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Gamma_distribution#References_that_seems_like_self_promotion. Also Berg & Pedersen did include an approximation that works near 0, which is an asymptotic approximation of this bound. And you can find a better asymptotic approximation from your bound (use Wofram Alpha, for example, to get rid of the gamma function). At that talk page and my user subpage I described a bunch of my attempts to find good approximations, over subsequent months.

Comment: I have recently streamlined some of that approach and wrote and submitted a paper on it, so maybe I'll be able to share that soon. But there are plenty of good approximations there for you to try.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $\mu_\alpha$ be the median of a $\Gamma(\alpha)$ distribution.  This means the area under the density $$f_{\Gamma(\alpha)}(x) = \frac{x^{\alpha-1}}{\Gamma(\alpha)} \,e^{-x}$$ between $x=0$ and $x=\mu_\alpha$ equals $1/2.$  A graph of $f_{\Gamma(\alpha)}$ is sketched here in black (for $\alpha=0.3$), understanding the graph extends infinitely upwards as $x$ approaches $0$ and flattens down to $0$ as $x$ grows large:

[image: Figure]

*The median $\mu_\alpha$ separates the left half of the area (darkened) from the right half.  The dotted red curve is an upper bound for the Gamma density, enabling a lower bound for the median to be found by using the area under the red curve instead of the gray area.*

$1 - x \le e^{-x} \le 1$ for $x \ge 0$ implies

$$\frac{x^{\alpha-1}}{\Gamma(\alpha)} \,(1-x) \le f_{\Gamma(\alpha)}(x) \le \frac{x^{\alpha-1}}{\Gamma(\alpha)}$$

which in turn gives
 $$ \int_0^{\mu_\alpha}\frac{x^{\alpha-1}}{\Gamma(\alpha)} \,(1-x)\,\mathrm{d}x \le \int_0^{\mu_\alpha}f_{\Gamma(\alpha)}(x)\,\mathrm{d}x =\frac{1}{2} \le \int_0^{\mu_\alpha}\frac{x^{\alpha-1}}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\,\mathrm{d}x.$$

Evaluating the integrals produces

$$ \frac{\mu_\alpha^\alpha}{\alpha\Gamma(\alpha)}\left(1 - \frac{\alpha}{\alpha+1}\mu_\alpha\right) \le \frac{1}{2} \le \frac{\mu_\alpha^\alpha}{\alpha\Gamma(\alpha)}. $$

This can be simplified a little by solving for $\mu_\alpha$ and recalling $z\Gamma(z) = \Gamma(z+1)$ for any $z:$

$$\mu_\alpha \ge \left(\frac{\Gamma(\alpha+1)}{2}\right)^{1/\alpha} \ge \mu_\alpha\left(1 - \frac{\alpha}{\alpha+1}\,\mu_\alpha\right)^{1/\alpha}.$$

One way to exploit the second inequality is to find a bound for $\mu_\alpha/\alpha$ when $0 \lt \alpha \le 1$.  This expression is increasing: we have

$$\frac{\mu_\alpha}{\alpha} = e^{-\varphi(\alpha)} $$

for $\varphi$ as defined in equation (3) in [Berg & Pedersen (2006)](https://doi.org/10.4310/MAA.2006.v13.n1.a4), and Proposition 3.6 in the same paper shows that $\varphi$ is decreasing.

Therefore the value of $\frac{\mu_\alpha}{\alpha}$ at $\alpha=1$, equal to $\log(2)$, provides an upper bound

$$\mu_\alpha \le \alpha \log(2).$$

Crude as this is, it enables us to eliminate $\mu_\alpha$ from the denominator of the right hand side by replacing it with its upper bound, yielding the bounds

> $$\left(\frac{\Gamma(\alpha+1)}{2}\right)^{1/\alpha} \le \mu_\alpha \le \left(\frac{\alpha + 1}{\alpha + 1 - \log(2) \alpha^2}\right)^{1/\alpha}\,\left(\frac{\Gamma(\alpha+1)}{2}\right)^{1/\alpha}.$$

Dividing these bounds by $\mu_\alpha$ gives the relative error plotted here:

[image: Figure 2: plot of the bounds as a function of alpha]

The lower bound clearly is an accurate approximation for $\alpha \lt 0.2,$ yielding at least two significant decimal digits, while the upper bound gives at least one significant digit throughout.

Having obtained definite bounds (useful for analysis), we may adjust them to produce even more accurate estimates.  For instance, $0.9075$ times the upper bound approximates $\mu_\alpha$ to within one percent relative accuracy when $0.16\le\alpha\le 1$ and $1.0035$ times the lower bound achieves $0.4\%$ relative accuracy for $\alpha \lt 0.16.$

Comment: I see you beat me to that good lower bound. I came up with the same a few weeks later, in the discussion on Wikipedia, at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Gamma_distribution#References_that_seems_like_self_promotion. Also Berg and Pedersen did include an approximation that works near 0, which is an asymptotic approximation of this bound. And you can find a better asymptotic approximation from your bound (use Wofram Alpha, for example, to get rid of the gamma function).
At that talk page and my user subpage I described a bunch of my attempts to find good approximations, over subsequent months

Answer (score 3):

Since these 2020 answers, I have published two peer-reviewed papers on this topic, with good bounds and approximations, over the entire parameter range (to infinity, not just 0 to 1), in 2021, and more, with rigorous proofs of the main bounds and some newer ones, in 2023.

In particular, a closed-form approximation that is exact at 1 is nice.  With one parameter variation, it can be made an upper bound or a lower bound, or can be adjusted to minimize the maximum error or the maximum relative error (parameter values, sometimes closed form, are tabulated, and errors plotted, for all these cases).  The maximum relative error can be less than 5e-3.  More elaborate versions with lower errors are also given.

https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0251626
"On closed-form tight bounds and approximations for the median of a gamma distribution"
and if you like proofs:
https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0288601
"Tight bounds for the median of a gamma distribution".

Answer (score 2):

The other answer by [whuber](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/919/whuber) gives some nice simple bounds for the median.  In this answer I will give an alternative closed form approximation based on finite Newton iteration to the true quantile.  My answer uses the [lower incomplete Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function) $\gamma$ (so perhaps you consider that cheating), but it does not require the inverse function.  in nay case, the quantile equation $F(x) = p$ can be written as:

$$\begin{align}
p = F(x) 
= \frac{\gamma(\alpha, x)}{\Gamma(\alpha)}.
\end{align}$$

We can rewrite this as the implicit equation $H(x|p,\alpha)=0$ using the function:

$$H(x|p,\alpha) \equiv \Big[ p \Gamma(\alpha) - \gamma(\alpha, x) \Big] e^x.$$

The first and second derivatives of this function are:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{dH}{dx}(x|p,\alpha) 
&= H(x|p,\alpha) - x^{\alpha-1}, \\[12pt]
\frac{d^2 H}{dx^2}(x|p,\alpha) 
&= H(x|p,\alpha) - x^{\alpha-1} - (\alpha-1) x^{\alpha-2}. \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

The second order Newton equation is:

$$x_{t+1} = x_t - \frac{H(x_t|p,\alpha)}{H(x_t|p,\alpha) - x_t^{\alpha-1}}
 \Bigg[ 1 + \frac{H(x_t|p,\alpha) (H(x_t|p,\alpha) - x^{\alpha-1} - (\alpha-1) x^{\alpha-2})}{2 (H(x_t|p,\alpha) - x^{\alpha-1})^2} \Bigg].$$

Unless I am mistaken, the initial power series here is valid for all $\alpha>0$ so it should work for the range of values of interest in your question.  If you start at a point reasonably close to the true quantile (e.g., one of the bounds that whuber gives in his answer), we would expect fairly rapid convergence to the true quantile.  Thus, a valid approximation to the true quantile would be to run this Newton iteration some finite number of steps.

---

**Testing this iterative method:** Here is a simple example to confirm that the iterative method is working.  Suppose we consider the median of the distribution $\text{Gamma}(2, 1)$.  We will start the iterative procedure at the upper-bound approximation in whuber's answer, which is:

$$x_0 = 2 \log 2 = 1.678347.$$

In the code below we will use $m = 4$ iterations of the Newton method, which gives the tiny approximation error of $-2.220446 \times 10^{-16}$.  This code uses second-order Newton, but it is possible to get quite a good approximation even with the first order approximation.

```
#Define the implicit function
H <- function(x, p, alpha) { 
  H <- gamma(alpha)*(p - pgamma(x, alpha, 1))*exp(x);
  attr(H, 'gradient') <- H - x^(alpha-1);
  attr(H, 'Hessian')  <- attributes(H)$gradient - (alpha-1)*x^(alpha-2);
  H; }

#Set the parameters
alpha <- 2;
p     <- 0.5;

#Perform m Newton iterations
m    <- 4;
x    <- rep(NA, m+1);
x[1] <- alpha*log(2);
for (t in 1:m) { 
  HHH <- H(x[t], p, alpha);
  HHD <- attributes(HHH)$gradient;
  HDD <- attributes(HHH)$gradient;
  x[t+1] <- x[t] - HHH/HHD*(1 + HHH*HDD/(2*HHD^2)); }

#Here is the approximation
x[m+1];
[1] 1.678347

#Here is the true median
qgamma(p, alpha, 1);
[1] 1.678347

#Here is the approximation error
x[m+1] - qgamma(p, alpha, 1)
[1] -2.220446e-16
```

Anyway, I'm not sure if this type of approximation is useful for your purposes, but it does involve a finite number of iterations.  Obviously it uses the evaluation of the incomplete Gamma function, so it is not "closed form".  It may be possible to create a closed form version by using a closed form approximation to the incomplete gamma function, and that would allow you to start at the approximation given by whuber, and then iterate towards the true median.

Comment: Would it be correct to understand this as a numerical evaluation of the median?

Comment: Yes, certainly.  Obviously it is much more complicated than your simpler bound, so I'm not sure if it is useful for Stephen's purposes.  Nevertheless, so long as he is willing to use ```pgamma``` in the evaluation, this is an approximation that also uses a finite number of operations.