# Can I say that the relative root mean squared error is the averaged percentage error?

Tags: forecasting, error, model-evaluation, rms

`RMSE` is an error metric in which the mean of the data minimizes its loss function:

$\text{RMSE} = \sqrt{\frac{\sum_{t=1}^{n}(y_t - \hat{y_t})^2}{n}}$

But it gives the error in the unit of the data.

In order to have a `percentage RMSE` [different alternatives exist](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/10/evaluation-metric-for-regression-models/#h-normalized-root-mean-squared-error-nrmse):

1. RMSE / $\text{max}(y_t)$
2. RMSE / $\text{mean}(y_t)$
3. RMSE / ($\text{max}(y_t) - \text{min}(y_t)$) #if mean is zero
4. RMSE / $\text{sd}(y_t)$
5. RMSE / $\text{IQR}(y_t)$

If I choose option 2, can I interpret it as simple as 'the average percentage error'? (Or should I say 'the weighted average percentage error'?) Given the fact that the interpretation of `RMSE` is the [weighted average error](https://stephenallwright.com/interpret-rmse/).

I want to make the interpretation as simple as possible for business people.

Thanks

Comment: No you cannot, since your rmse might be arbitrary large, so you will not necessarily have a value in $[0, 1]$. Also, what if your mean of $y_t$ is zero? Maybe you can explain what exactly you are trying to achieve with such a new metric.

Comment: Why can I not? Is it because any of the 5 vary between $(-\infty, +\infty)$? If the mean of $y_t$ is zero I could use option 3. MAPE is a very appealing error metric because it is easy to explain, and the business uses it a lot (without labeling it). However, there are many flaws. So, I want a percentage metric based on RMSE that is easy to explain to the businesses (or that their acceptance will be fast).

Comment: (2) estimates the [coefficient of variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_variation#Estimation).  It's okay to divide by $n$ in the "RMSE" calculation but most often the denominator is $n-df$ where $df$ regression parameters are employed in estimating $\hat y_t.$ Calling it an "average percentage error" is a mischaracterization, because the latter is English for $(100/n)\sum |y_t-\hat y_t|/y_t.$ Either concept is problematic when any of the $y_t$ might be non-positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I would be very careful about interpreting the RMSE as a "weighted average error". Yes, larger errors add more to the RMSE than smaller ones... But it's simply not the case that the RMSE is a weighted sum of some quantities that are errors in themselves. (The wMAPE, in contrast, *can* be so interpreted, [Kolassa & Schütz, 2007](https://econpapers.repec.org/article/forijafaa/y_3a2007_3ai_3a6_3ap_3a40-43.htm), but it has its own issues.)

Second, you can certainly scale the RMSE by some quantity and express the result as a percentage. It would then be a percentage *of* or *with respect to* that scaling denominator. As long as your denominator is positive, this is at least well-defined, but it may not give you the kind of information you or your audience needs.

I see such "scaled" RMSEs more often referred to as, well, a "scaled RMSE".

As identified in the comments, all your proposed candidates can result in errors that exceed 1, or 100% - just like the standard Mean Absolute Percentage Error can exceed 100%. This is often disconcerting to a non-technical audience. For the standard MAPE, this can be avoided by using a flat zero forecast (which is usually no use to anybody).

Forecast accuracy measurement [is unfortunately harder than it looks](https://forecasting-encyclopedia.com/theory.html#point_forecast_accuracy_measures), especially if the "accuracy" is used as a target to be "improved", which can lead to all kinds of gaming - like setting forecasts to a hard zero per above. Forecasters have to educate their audience not to over-interpret errors, and to focus more on the *implications* of forecast errors (e.g., [Kolassa, 2023](https://econpapers.repec.org/article/forijafaa/y_3a2023_3ai_3a68_3ap_3a20-24.htm)). Yes, this is often hard, and very unintuitive.

You may already have seen this: [What are the shortcomings of the Mean Absolute Percentage Error (MAPE)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/299712/1352)

Comment: What do you mean by "like setting forecasts to a hard zero per above"? My naive interpretation is that you set y_hat = 0. But I don't think that it is it...

Comment: Oh yes indeed, that is what I meant. Assume you want to point forecast a gamma distributed variable with shape parameter $0<k\leq 1$, in a way that you minimize the expected MAPE. (Thus your realizations will be strictly positive, so you won't be dividing by zero in calculating the MAPE.) You will find that [the best point forecast is a flat zero](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/389318/1352). Don't take my word for it; simulate a bunch of iid gamma variates with a shape parameter less than one, and check the MAPE for various possible point forecasts.